# How do I push value into an array that's defined in the viewModel?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2, and what I plan on achieving is:

I have a class, that has a ViewModel defined. I need to create an array for the ViewModel and set values to that array, so I can access it in the view.

So, In a class, I have the following:

```
$viewModel = new Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewModel->setVariable('fields', array( ));
```

This means, I am creating an array called formFields that is accessible in the view. Now, How do I push a value into this array, from my model class? Trying the following doesn't seem to work:

```
$viewModel->setVariable('fields[]', $field);
```

Thanks,

Comment: BTW. why set up a ViewModel in a "model class"? I usually use them in my controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass it during declaration:

```
$viewModel->setVariable('fields', array(
    'key' => 'value',
    ...
));
```

or assign the value to variable, do what you need to do with it, and then set it on the viewModel object.

You can also get the variable, change it's value and set it again in place. E.g.:

```
$arr = $viewModel->geVariable('fields');
array_push($arr, 'value');
$viewModel->setVariable('fields[]', $arr);
```